# How to set a static array in a specific memory location

Tags: c

I am running this c program in gcc.
The below works for one variable.

```
#define dataBlk_tx0 ((volatile unsigned int *) 0x20000ACB)
```

But if I want to create an array and write to it how would I do this, this array needs to be defined before main?

```
#define dataBlk_tx0 ((volatile unsigned int * x[8]) 0x20000ACB)

main{

dataBlk_tx0[0] = 5;

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to _create_ an array? The array is already there, it's the memory `dataBlk_tx0` points to. Just use it like this: `dataBlk_tx0[0]`, `dataBlk_tx0[1]`  etc. Just use `#define dataBlk_tx0 ((volatile unsigned int *) 0x20000ACB)` (without the final `;`)

Comment: You _could_ define it as `#define dataBlk_tx0 ((volatile unsigned int (*)[8]) 0x20000ACB)`, but then you would need to access the elements using constructions such as `(*dataBlk_tx0)[0] = 5;` or `dataBlk_tx0[0][0] = 5;`, so it would be much simpler to follow @Jabberwocky's suggestion in the comment above to avoid the need for the extra level of dereferencing/indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read or write directly to that address and memory, you can do it like this:

1. Initialize `dataBlk_tx0` as a pointer to the specific memory location
2. Access that memory through the pointer.

```
volatile unsigned int * dataBlk_tx0 = (unsigned int *)0x20000ACB;

int main () {
    dataBlk_tx0[0] = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to create an array in a specific memory *region* (like Flash vs RAM on a micocontroller), then you'll need to look into linker scripts.